# Asp.core JWT and external authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, blazor, openid

I'm in a scenario where there is a Blazor app that has to be protected.
This app need a login on local user store or external auth on google or facebook or MS.

There is a asp.net core project that expose all the API for this Blazor app.
All API are protected [Authorize] and this api project implement also the login api that generate the JWT token.

Whit a local login, the login page was on the Blazor app that called login api, managed the response retriving JWT and store in the local storage. For each request Blazor app sent JWT token to authorized api.

How to manage External Authentication in this case? Is Blazor app that has to generate the call to Google, facebook,... and then the google callback will call the api project to generate the jwt ?
I cannot understand how to let the flow work, as api are protected by JWT, and I guess external authentication has to callback the api to generate jwt, but I how to return back to the Blazor app?

I dont' want to use Identity Server 4 , but I could externalize login page on api project.

Comment: `Whit a local login, the login page was on the Blazor app that called login api, managed the response retriving JWT and store in the local storage.` Can you share the detailed code, so that we can understand the requirement better.